# EXCEL OleDbCommand Select statement No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: sql, excel, oledbcommand

I am querying and excel spreadsheet and I want to add columns in the select.

```sql
SELECT "500" AS [COMPENDIUM_ID], 
       [ORDER_CODE], 
       [ORDER_DESCRIPTION] AS [ORDER_DESC], 
       "NULL" AS [AOE_CAT_CODE_ID], 
       [ORDER_LOINC_CODE],  
       [LOINC_CODE], 
       "Y" AS [ACTIVE], 
       "SYSDATE" AS [TIMESTAMP], 
       "1" AS [MODIFIED_BY] 
FROM [Sheet1$]
```

This throws an error of

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Can you try with single quotes instead of the double quotes? '500' instead of "500" etc.

Comment: I figured it out, the column names in the spreadsheet are really F1, F2,F3 etc... not the header value [ORDER_CODE] double quotes works fine.